# How do I force OS X to treat a file as a Folder?

Tags: finder, folders

I happened to name some of my photo folders "*.Playground" (e.g., some date plus the ".Playground"), it got picked up happily by Xcode and now OS X treats it like a file associated with Xcode, even changing the filename doesn't help.

Does anyone know a way to force the file to be treated as a Folder?

Comment: I am ok with changing the folder name by the way, it is just that even after doing so Finder still treats it as a package

Answer (score 2):

I created a folder with two .jpg files in it, and renamed the folder "Today.Playground". As you say, it got associated with Xcode. (Nifty icon!)

So I changed the name to "Today.layground". At first, Finder wouldn't show me what was in it. (That is, I was viewing it in column view, and column to the right showed a preview of a generic folder, instead of listing what was in it.) I clicked on another item and then clicked on the folder again, and Finder properly showed the two .jpg files still inside.

It appears to me that that's all you have to do: look away and then look again.

Comment: I had file in the folder but "looking away and looking again" didn't work for me (I even restarted the mac)

Comment: I tried again, this time even going so far as to double-click on the .Playground so that Xcode would try to open it. (It said "the file could not be opened".) I wanted to see if Xcode did something horrible to the folder, like delete all the .jpg files. Same result. All I had to do was change the extension and then de-select and re-select the folder to get Finder to see it as a folder again with its files intact. I'm on OS X 10.10.1, running Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: select the folder, select "File" -> "get info" (or click ⌘i),check the "name & Extension".

Answer (score 2):

But thanks to ganbustein@'s answer, which led me to find the solution (since I wanted to create the jpg files via commandline):

I noticed that even though I changed the name to something else via Finder, it still appends a hidden extension of (.playground) to it, so I just renamed the folders there and the folders are back!

Alternatively, I think if I had Finder show extensions for all files and I can do the renaming in Finder as well.

Comment: Ah, that's it. I always have extensions shown.